# useEffect run multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My requirement is as below.

1. Filter state changes -> page state should be set to 1, then getData() should run
2. Page state changes -> getData() should run

I tried to write above scenarios as below.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setPage(1);
}, [filters]);

useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, [filters, page]);
```

But, during the first scenario, getData() runs twice. Appreciate if someone can help out to sort out this matter.

Comment: It's expected that effects run twice in strict mode

Comment: Can you simply remove "filters" from the second useEffect dependancy array?

Comment: According to the first requirement, add getData() to the first useEffect. And remove filters from the dependency array for the second useEffect.

Answer (score 1):

When strict mode is activated in react, it is normal that useEffect is activated twice, to deactivate strict mode you can delete the   tags, by default they come where the rootElement is being created, example:

```
import React, { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
   <StrictMode>
     <App />
   </StrictMode>
);
```

Another reason why this scenario is happening is that: When updating the filter state, the two useEffects will be activated since [filters] is being passed in the parameters, this way, getData() will be called in the second useEffect and when running the first useEffect which changes the state of the page, the second useEffect will be called again since [page] is being passed in the parameter of the second useEffect.
I think this way would solve your problem:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setPage(1);
}, [filters]);

useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, [page]);
```